# Drop empty interaction terms in 'brms'

Tags: r, brms

In the following example, I have assumed that the interaction term "var1a:var2z" is dropped because it is empty (as in rstanarm).

```
data <- data.frame(y=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   var1=c("a","a","b","b","b"),
                   var2=c("x","y","x","y","z"))
fit <- brms::brm("y~-1+var1:var2",data=data)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't the case, and I don't understand why.

Win 10 
R 4.3.0 
brms 2.20.3

Comment: Why are you assuming this? Why not just drop it yourself if it's "empty"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'drop it yourself'? The interaction term is not present in the data, but is treated as such in the fit. This leads to unnecessary problems for this particular term (large r-hat value, etc.).

Comment: Why are you including the interaction in the first place if it's not desired?

Comment: I want the interaction between var1 and var2, but only those that are present in the data. How would you formulate the formula in this case?